# SQL Server XML modify with no result

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an xml document like

```
<xsd:form-definition ...>
   <xsd:page ..></xsd:page>
   <xsd:page ..></xsd:page>
...
</xsd:form-definition>
```

and I want to insert a new node in the first `<xsd:page>` element

```
DECLARE @res XML = '<Subject>English</Subject>'

SET @myXmlContent.modify('insert sql:variable("@res") as first into (/form-definition/page)[1]')
```

but nothing changes, why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XQuery for your modify needs to declare and reference the `xsd` namespace:

```
SET @myXmlContent.modify('declare namespace xsd="..."; insert sql:variable("@res") as first into (/xsd:form-definition/xsd:page)[1]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT @XML = 
'<xsd_form-definition>
   <xsd_page></xsd_page>
   <xsd_page></xsd_page>
</xsd_form-definition>'

DECLARE @res XML = '<VehicleManufacturerID>abc</VehicleManufacturerID>'

SELECT @XML.modify('insert sql:variable("@res") into (xsd_form-definition/xsd_page)[1]')

SELECT @XML
```