# SQL Server XML manipulation - Only non-document nodes can be inserted

Tags: sql-server, xml

accorgind to the topic [SQL Server XML modify with no result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059591/sql-server-xml-modify-with-no-result) while before insert the new node I get the error

```
XQuery [modify()]: Only non-document nodes can be inserted. Found "xs:string ?".
```

the body of the new node :

```
<formant id="'+lower(newid())+'" name="_name" width="155" height="20" x="125" y="761"
         tabindex="0" source-name="_sn" readonly="false" required="false"
         font="_fnt"><value></value></formant>
```

any ideas how to fix it ?

```
DECLARE @newNodeData varchar(max) = <formant id="'+lower(newid())+'" name="_name" width="155" height="20" x="125" y="761"
                                    tabindex="0" source-name="_sn" readonly="false" required="false"
                                    font="_fnt"><value></value></formant>
```

...some text modifications on the @newNodeData variable

then

```
declare @xml xml;

select @xml = t.xmlData //t.xmlData is ntext type
from table t
where id=123

set @xml.modify('declare namespace xsd="http://www.cebip.pl/xml/schematy/formularze/v1.0/definicja-formularza.xsd"; insert sql:variable("@newNodeData") as first into (/xsd:form-definition/xsd:page)[1]')

update table
set xmlData = @newNodeData 
where id=123
```

Comment: Give the exact SQL for what you're trying to do

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do text modifications, do these on a `varchar(max)`, but then store the result in a final XML variable that you then use in your `modify()`

```
DECLARE @newNodeDataTmp varchar(max) = '<formant id="'+lower(newid())+'" name="_name" width="155" height="20" x="125" y="761"
                                    tabindex="0" source-name="_sn" readonly="false" required="false"
                                    font="_fnt"><value></value></formant>'

-- Modifications

declare @newNodeData xml = cast(@newNodeDataTmp as xml)
```

The variable you use in your `modify()` is going to need to be of XML type.